# Rodeo clutch slips

Tags: clutch

I just bought a 98 rodeo 2wd v6. The clutch was fine on test drive and grabbed fine even though the pedal was adjusted to the top. When I was driving it home it started to slip. Is there a way to adjust it more as it at the top of the pedal now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is fully adjusted (to the top, as you put it), there is no way to "get a little more" out of it. The clutch is done and you should consider getting it replaced very soon. You will be not only wasting money in gas (due to slippage), but you will also run the risk of damaging other parts, such as the flywheel (I bet this is already damaged, anyway). Even if you could adjust it a "little more", it would only be a stop-gap measure. It would need to be replaced in the near future regardless.

On a separate note, I think you already understand this, but if this were bought at dealership, there would also be no way to take it back to the seller to get it replaced unless it is agreed to prior to purchase (this may not be so in California, as they have some pretty wild consumer protection laws). This is in the United States, or course. What the deal is, used cars purchased from a dealership, if out of warranty, are sold "as-is" unless specifically stated in the purchase of the vehicle. Some dealerships offer a 30-day or 3,000 mile powertrain warranty (or something similar). If you were given this at the outset of the purchase, you may have recourse. If not, this repair is going to be all on you.